# ODBC connections not visible in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have installed informatica power center 9 with SQL server in Win 7. I created source / target dbs in sql and test connected with Informatica.

My problem arised when i tried to import the source database structure using Informatica source analyzer. I created ODBC connections but when I tried to locate them from Informatica designer's source analyzer, no connections are listed there which i created.

Can anyone throw some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The bitness of the PowerCenter client and the ODBC connection have to match. If you have a 32-bit client, use 32-bit drivers; otherwise, go for the 64-bit ones.

Comment: You could also create the odbc connection when you are trying to import the source